# Disk Failure is Imminent after Partion with gParted

Tags: gparted, fdisk, disk-utility, testdisk

I was trying to partition my drive. I used gparted live iso using usb drive. It partitioned successfully but when I logged in Ubuntu again it is showing some problem in my hard drive. Error is Disk Failure is Imminent. How to resolve it? Is there any fix or I have to change my Hard drive ??

Answer (score 1):

These events are unrelated. Partitioning is not a cause for the diagnostics on a hard drive to fail. Your hard drive is likely to fail soon and it's just a **coincidence** this happens after using a partitioning tool.

Back up your data soon and replace the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Ubuntu, run the Disks tool and check the S.M.A.R.T data for that drive to see what the problem may be...  Maybe Gparted picked up on something while you were partitioning the drive itself and Ubuntu is reporting a problem because of it...

Answer (score 0):

If there are errors, it might be that your drive is a bit damaged inside. Your USB drive might have aged. This is normal. Therefore, your disk has a self-monitoring and  early-warning system built-in which tries to notify you of its aging. Replace the drive soon.

To get more info abot the damage:
Run; (or install, and then run) *gnome-disks*.

You'll see something like this.

[image: smart-disktools]

[image]

Alternatively, you may as well keep/put  unimportant data on this disk,  until it finally fails.

**There is nothing you can do to fix it (inexpensively). Disk failure is an unpredicatable, "statistical" process.**